# using angularjs in xhtml

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xhtml

I used an angular-route.js file and data-ng-app="angular-app". app.js:

```
'use strict';
var angular_app = angular.module('angular_app', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

index.html:

```
..
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="angular_app">
..
```

Why https://validator.w3.org/check display errors:

```
Line 32, Column 20: there is no attribute "data-ng-app"
<div data-ng-app="angular_app" class="container">
```

Thank you:

Comment: because its custom attribute(used as directive) to initialize angular on page..

Comment: Is your site actually an XHTML document, or is it an HTML document with an XHTML doctype? If the latter, just change the doctype to the one for HTML5. I'm asking because its name is index.html according to the question, which means it's HTML.

Comment: Yes, i'm aplying to an job and the employer gave an test tasks about xhtml, and the best i'm using the angularjs because it's comfortable thing to do ajax applications.